# VMware tools patching - Kernel 2.6.37+ (Slackware 13.37) Graphics Drivers Not Working

Tags: linux, vmware, kernel, linux-kernel, slackware

Good day,

I am using Slackware 13.1 in VMware Fusion 3 (latest) on my OSX10.6 laptop.

I recently upgraded my Slackware 13.1 machine which is directly installed on a spare PC to Slackware 13.37, no issues. I did the same upgrade on my Slackware VM, and all hell has broken loose.

It seems that the latest version of VMware tools installed in my guest VM just don't work, and the VM is completely unusable.

I have gone through a number of patches I have found on blogs, etc, but none seem to be helpful in my case. Is anyone familiar with any kernel patches or manual patches that exist for VMware tools to support Xorg 1.9.5?

I have attached my log below which I get when I either attempt to update or reinstall VMware tools on my guest VM. The most concerning part is the "skipping X configuration" portion below.

Thank you.

```
Initializing...


Making sure services for VMware Tools are stopped.

Stopping VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:
Guest operating system daemon:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Virtual Printing daemon:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
VMware User Agent (vmware-user):[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Blocking file system:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Unmounting HGFS shares:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Guest filesystem driver:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
VM communication interface socket family:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
VM communication interface:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]


The module vmmemctl has already been installed on this system by another
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer. Use the flag
--clobber-kernel-modules=vmmemctl to override.

Initializing...

Initializing...


Making sure services for VMware Tools are stopped.

Stopping VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:
Guest operating system daemon:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Virtual Printing daemon:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
VMware User Agent (vmware-user):[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Blocking file system:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Unmounting HGFS shares:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
Guest filesystem driver:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
VM communication interface socket family:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]
VM communication interface:[60G[[1;32m OK [0;39m]


The module vmmemctl has already been installed on this system by another
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer. Use the flag
--clobber-kernel-modules=vmmemctl to override.

make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/message.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/dir.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/cpName.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/request.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/stubs.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/tcp.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/link.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/bdhandler.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/transport.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/module.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/file.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/backdoorGcc32.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/super.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/kernelStubsLinux.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/fsutil.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLinux.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/hgfsBd.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/page.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/backdoor.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/hgfsEscape.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/inode.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/messageBackdoor.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/dentry.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLite.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only'
cp -f vmhgfs.ko ./../vmhgfs.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only'

make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet-only'
cp -f vmxnet.ko ./../vmxnet.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet-only'

make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/filesystem.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/stubs.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/dbllnklst.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/file.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/block.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/module.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/super.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/control.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/inode.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/linux/dentry.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/vmblock.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/vmblock.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only/vmblock.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only'
cp -f vmblock.ko ./../vmblock.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only'

make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciProcess.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciGuestDs.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciDatagram.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci_drv.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciEvent.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/kernelStubsLinux.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciQueuePair.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciKernelIf.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciUtil.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciGuestKernelIf.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
cp -f vmci.ko ./../vmci.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'

make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciProcess.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciGuestDs.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciDatagram.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci_drv.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciEvent.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/kernelStubsLinux.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciQueuePair.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciKernelIf.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciUtil.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmciGuestKernelIf.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only/vmci.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
cp -f vmci.ko ./../vmci.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only'
make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/linux/af_vsock.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/linux/vsockAddr.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/linux/util.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/linux/stats.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/linux/notify.o
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/driverLog.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/vsock.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/vsock.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only/vsock.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only'
cp -f vsock.ko ./../vsock.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only'

make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet3-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet3-only/vmxnet3.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet3-only/vmxnet3.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet3-only/vmxnet3.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet3-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet3-only'
cp -f vmxnet3.ko ./../vmxnet3.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmxnet3-only'

make: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/pvscsi-only'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.37.6-smp/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
CC [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/pvscsi-only/pvscsi.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /tmp/vmware-root/modules/pvscsi-only/pvscsi.mod.o
LD [M] /tmp/vmware-root/modules/pvscsi-only/pvscsi.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.37.6'
make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/pvscsi-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/pvscsi-only'
cp -f pvscsi.ko ./../pvscsi.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/pvscsi-only'

Detected Xorg X server version 1.9.5.

Distribution provided drivers for Xorg X server are used.

Skipping X configuration because X drivers are not included
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, at the recommendation of a colleague, I migrated over to VirtualBox.